# How can I set a variable value in a template based on a registered systemd version

Tags: ansible

So using `systemctl --version | grep systemd | awk  '{print $2}'` I can find version of systemd, now I want to register the varibale that stores true or false based on fact whether the value is 245 or much older or is it greater than 245.

I have put together these Ansible tasks:

```yaml
- name:  get systemd version fact
  become: yes
  shell: systemctl --version | grep systemd | awk  '{print $2}'
  register: systemd_version

- name: Setup consul.conf in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d for systemd version 245 and older
  become: yes
  tags: ["never", "systemd"]
  when: inventory_hostname != 'proxy' && (systemd_version <= 245)
  copy:
    dest: /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/consul.conf
    content: |
      [Resolve]
      DNS=127.0.0.1
      DNSSEC=false
      Domains=~consul

- name: Setup consul.conf in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d for systemd version greater than 245
  become: yes
  tags: ["never", "systemd"]
  when: inventory_hostname != 'proxy' && (systemd_version >= 245)
  copy:
    dest: /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/consul.conf
    content: |
      [Resolve]
      DNS=127.0.0.1:8600
      DNSSEC=false
      Domains=~consul
```

Is this something that can be put into one task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can template the `content`, and use an [inline-if](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#if-expression):

```yaml
content: |
  [Resolve]
  DNS=127.0.0.1{{ ':8600' if systemd_version | int > 245 }}
  DNSSEC=false
  Domains=~consul
```

---

I would also advise you to use facts, and in this use case [`package_facts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/package_facts_module.html), instead of a `shell` module in order to get information on a package.

There is also a [`version`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#comparing-versions) test purposed to compare versions, that you should take advantage of.

So, here would be an example achieving you requirements:

```yaml
- block:
    - name: Gather packages information
      package_facts:

    - name: Setup consul.conf
      copy:
        dest: /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/consul.conf
        content: |
          [Resolve]
          DNS=127.0.0.1{{ ':8600' if systemd_version is version(245, '>') }}
          DNSSEC=false
          Domains=~consul
      vars:
        systemd_version: "{{ ansible_facts.packages.systemd[0].version }}"

  become: yes
  tags:
    - never
    - systemd
  when: inventory_hostname != 'proxy'
```

Comment: on some nodes `.` is the delimiter for version and on some node `-` is the delimiter , so I ended up using my way.

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz actually, there is an even better idea for version comparison, this has been edited in the answer.